# Adding specific dots to a series plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, data-visualization

I have a time series plot and I would like to add a red dot at a specific time index. Below is a sample code:

```
    dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01','2020-05-01'])
    series = pd.Series([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.5,6.7], index = dt_index)
    dots_to_add = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-04-01'])
    series.plot()
```

[image]

Using `dots_to_add` as an index, how would I add a red dot to the line?

Comment: Did you tried with plt.axis(...) ?

Comment: Doesn't plt.axis() just limit the x and y axis? I am looking to add a red dot to (x = '2020-01-01', y = 1.1) and (x = '2020-04-01', y = 4.5). Sorry maybe my question was not too clear.

Comment: Not a Pandas guy, but you can do `ax = series.plot()` and later `ax.scatter(…., color='red')` where with the ellipsis I have indicated some Pandish thing that in Numpy would be `ax.scatter(some_abscissae, all_ordinates[some_abscissae], color='red')` — nb this is not an answer 'cs I don't know enough Pandas to give a full answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dot in plot is called [marker](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01','2020-05-01'])
series = pd.Series([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.5,6.7], index = dt_index)
dots_to_add = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-04-01'])
series.plot(marker='o')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I don't find an parameter to make marker color and plot color different. I think there is none, because a marker is a part of plot, they should have the same style.

But I think you can draw a scatter plot instead:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01','2020-05-01'])
series = pd.Series([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.5,6.7], index = dt_index)
dots_to_add = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-04-01'])

series.plot()
plt.scatter(series.index, series, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you just want to add dots with `dots_to_add` as an index, you could just use a `for` loop with each loop `plt.scatter()` a dot.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt_index = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01','2020-05-01'])
series = pd.Series([1.1,2.2,3.3,4.5,6.7], index = dt_index)
dots_to_add = pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01','2020-04-01'])

series.plot()

for dot in dots_to_add:
    plt.scatter(dot, series[dot], color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]